# why am I getting a missing link or not set error

Tags: php

I am just wondering if we need to have the !isset function for email activation because we are not really filling out a form to check if the user has submitted the form or not but a link instead. I read somewhere that email activation can fail and one should also allow the user to activate their account manually but the following code should work but sometimes I do get the missing link error. However, all the variables are shown in my url though:

```
<?php
include_once __DIR__.'/header2.php';
if($_SESSION['u_uid']) {
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?activatelevel2promo=mustloggedoutfirst'>";
     exit();
} else {

if (!isset($_GET['email']) || !isset($_GET['activatetoken']) || !isset($_GET['duration'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?activatelevel2promo=missinglink'>";
     exit();
} else {

  include_once __DIR__.'/dbh.php';






  // retrieve the email and token from url
  $activate = 0;
  $email = strip_tags($_GET['email']);
  $token =  strip_tags($_GET['activatetoken']);
  $duration = strip_tags($_GET['duration']);



$sql = "SELECT * FROM memberships WHERE user_email = ? AND token2 = ? AND activate2 = ?;";

 $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        //Prepare the prepared stement

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "SQL statement failed";

            } else {
             //Bind parameters to the placeholder
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssi", $email, $token, $activate);
             mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

             $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
             $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
             if ($resultCheck > 0) {

            $subscriptionplandate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $level2promo_activate = 1;
            if($duration == '1week') {
                $expirydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 week"));
            }

            if($duration == '2weeks') {
                $expirydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+2 week"));
            }

            if($duration == '3weeks') {
                $expirydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+3 week"));
            }

            if($duration == '4weeks') {
                $expirydate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 month"));
            }



           $token = null;

            $sql2 = "UPDATE memberships
                    SET subscriptionplandate2 = ?, expirydate2 = ?, token2 = ?, level2promo_activate = ?
                    WHERE user_email = ?;
                   ";

            $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        //Prepare the prepared stement

        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql2)) {
            echo "SQL statement failed";

            } else {
             //Bind parameters to the placeholder
             mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssis", $subscriptionplandate, $expirydate, $token, $level2promo_activate, $email);
             mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);



            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=../index.php?activatelevel2promo=success'>";
            exit();

 }
}
}
}
} 

This is what is been shown in the url:

https://www.pianocourse101.com/includes/activatelevel2promo.php?email=pianoforte0011@gmail.com&activatetoken=%5E#%rG%5EGTq@&duration=2weeks
```

Answer (score 0):

> because we are not really filling out a form to check if the user has submitted the form or not but a link instead

That doesn’t matter. Same as I could not fill out or remove a form field named `foo`, I could also remove a parameter `?bar=...` from any URL before I call it - the result would be the same, a parameter your script is expecting, resp. *needs* to be able to properly perform its task, isn’t there. So yes, checking whether you got all the data you need, makes sense in both cases.

> but the following code should work but sometimes I do get the missing link error. However, all the variables are shown in my url though

Yeah, well …

```
…?email=pianoforte0011@gmail.com&activatetoken=%5E#%rG%5EGTq@&duration=2weeks
```

What you have here, is one parameter with the name `email` and the value `pianoforte0011@gmail.com`, and one parameter named `activatetoken` with the value `%5E`, or `^` after URL decoding … and that’s it.

The rest of that URL is just the fragment identifier or “hash” - and that does not even get send to the server in the first place.

You neglected to properly URL-encode your parameter values here. The `#` is not supposed to have its special meaning here, so it needs to be encoded (`%23`)

You should either apply `urlencode` to all parameter values individually; or collect all your parameters and values in an array first, and then use `http_build_query` - that will do the complete job of creating the whole query string for you, and it takes care of the necessary encoding automatically while doing so.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using htmlspecialchars, would this be enough? Do I still have to use urlencoding?

Comment: You always need to treat data appropriately for the _context_ you are putting it in. The primary context here is “URL query string”, so URL encoding needs to be applied. (After that, you bring the value into the context “HTML”, by outputting it as the href of a link, so that is where htmlspecialchars should be applied. At least theoretically, because URL-encoding does not leave any characters that would have a special meaning in the first place, <, >, " … all that gets encoded to “harmless” %xy-values anyway.)

Comment: thanks for the advice... I think you could be right about how there might be some missing characters due to not using the url encoding... will give that a go!

Comment: This is not only missing characters, `$_GET['duration']` won’t even be set, because it is only part of the fragment/hash here. That’s why you get the "missinglink" error, because the non-existence of that parameter makes the whole if condition false.